# Essential smartphone apps for field recording?

Tags: field-recording, productivity, workflow

I personally have an iphone and I use the living heck out it when going out for a shoot - planned or otherwise.  Here's my list:

- Maps

Top of my list.  I use it to bookmark locations that may or may not be interesting in the future.  I'll pull over and roll down the window, then whip out the phone and drop a pin fairly frequently.

- Camera or hipstamatic

I really love the camera on the phone, and these days I never record anything without snapping a pic of it.  Hipstamatic is cool.  Here's a tree I recorded today shot with hipstamatic.  It makes me happy.  :)

[image]

- [Audio Tool](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/audio-tool/id379146462?mt=8).

DB meter and bit calculator so that I can see how much space I have on my cards at various sample/bit rates.  The dictionary is kind of interesting too.

- [Weatherbug](http://weather.weatherbug.com/mobile/weatherbug-for-iphone.html)

probably the best weather app available - has moving doppler radar, forecasts and even webcam views.

- [Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/iphoneapp) and [goodreader](http://www.goodiware.com/goodreader.html)

pdf readers that can download files locally so you don't need interent access to grab them.  I use them to store manuals and other useful technical stuff on the go.

- [Todo](http://www.appigo.com/todo)

productivity and listmaking app.  Great for putting together checklists for project and equipment.  I use it both in macro and micro contexts - making sure that my various projects don't take on too much rust while helping micromanage the stuff i'm working on right now.  Syncs with todledoo and remember the milk.

- [Younote lite](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/younote-lite/id284969305?mt=8)

regular notes, voice notes, picture notes with geotagging, freehand drawing, and a web broswer.  I mostly use it to snap a photo of something and add a note to the photo - often for when I find an interesiting location to record.  The photos it takes geotag and integrate directly with maps, and each photo has spots for notes.  really great for grabbing something that you'd othwerwise drive by and forget about.

- [flightaware](http://flightaware.com/live/airport_status_bigmap.rvt?airport=KDAL)

not an app but a website that I access from my phone when on the go.  live air traffic tracker, and iphone compatible.

---

ok, what did I miss?  what do you use on the go, and how do you use it?  mobile websites anyone?  android?

thx!

Answer (score 2):

I'm on Android with an HTC Desire and for me it'd be:

- Power Notes for text notes, snapshots
- the stock Voice Recorder app
- I do have an SPL meter app but not calibrated...

Answer (score 1):

I also use an iPhone.  Here is my essential app list (limited to field recording)
camera,
voice memos,
notes,
weather,
clockedin - time tracking app,
mapminders - allows me to drop a pin at a geo location and set a reminder message based on proximity to the pin.  good for reminding myself of cool locations or sounds.
RTA,
Decible Meter,
backline calc - length, pitch, timecode, electric, acoustics, and file size calculator
FiRe - 16/44100 audio recorder that supports photos, location info, uploads to soundcloud or ftp within the app...etc., and last but not least is not an app but always in my pocket is an iRec 03P by Logitec Corperation - xy stereo mic for iPhone

Answer (score 1):

On the iPhone, the iProRecorder is a very handy application. It does geographical location tagging, has a jog wheel with adjustable playback speed. Lots of features. When I got it was 99 cents. Now it's $4.99...

Answer (score 0):

Just a mention to audioboo for iphone and ipod touch. It's free, you can record, share your recordings with the community, find recordings around the world or near your location, has geotag... external mic needed for serious stuff...

Comment: I've got this for my Droid. Haven't used it much. But i really love the concept. 